# How can i prevent sql injection with codeiginiter

Tags: php, mysql, code-injection

I want to prevent my statement for injection but i am getting confused about active records and query bindings.

This is my current mysql query called results.

```
$results = $this->EE->db->query("SELECT t.transactionid, t.transactiontime, t.created, ct.title, cd.field_id_6, cd.field_id_5, cd.field_id_7, t.pricebefordiscount, t.priceafterdiscount, t.error, t.cardid, em.email, emd.m_field_id_2, emd.m_field_id_6, emd.m_field_id_5, emd.m_field_id_7, emd.m_field_id_4, t.restaurant_id
FROM exp_members as em
   INNER JOIN transactions as t on (em.member_id = t.cardid-10000000)
   INNER JOIN exp_channel_titles as ct on (t.restaurant_id = ct.entry_id)
   INNER JOIN exp_channel_data as cd on (ct.entry_id = cd.entry_id)
   INNER join exp_member_data as emd on em.member_id = emd.member_id
WHERE em.member_id = '".($_GET['cardid']-10000000)."'");
```

And this is how i tried to prevent mysql injection. Is this safe enough?

```
$results = $this->EE->db->query("SELECT t.transactionid, t.transactiontime, t.created, ct.title, cd.field_id_6, cd.field_id_5, cd.field_id_7, t.pricebefordiscount, t.priceafterdiscount, t.error, t.cardid, em.email, emd.m_field_id_2, emd.m_field_id_6, emd.m_field_id_5, emd.m_field_id_7, emd.m_field_id_4, t.restaurant_id
FROM exp_members as em
   INNER JOIN transactions as t on (em.member_id = t.cardid-10000000)
   INNER JOIN exp_channel_titles as ct on (t.restaurant_id = ct.entry_id)
   INNER JOIN exp_channel_data as cd on (ct.entry_id = cd.entry_id)
   INNER join exp_member_data as emd on em.member_id = emd.member_id
WHERE em.member_id = '".$this->db->escape(($_GET['cardid']-10000000))."'");
```

But is this also an option or ?

```
$this->load->database();
$this->load->library('table');

$this->db->select(' t.transactionid, t.transactiontime, t.created, ct.title, cd.field_id_6, cd.field_id_5, cd.field_id_7, t.pricebefordiscount, t.priceafterdiscount, t.error, t.cardid, em.email, emd.m_field_id_2, emd.m_field_id_6, emd.m_field_id_5, emd.m_field_id_7, emd.m_field_id_4, t.restaurant_id');
$this->db->from('exp_members'); 
$this->db->join('transactions', 'exp_members.member_id = transactions.cardid-10000000', 'inner');
$this->db->join('exp_channel_titles', 'transactions.restaurant_id = exp_channel_titles.entry_id', 'inner');
$this->db->join('exp_channel_data', 'exp_channel_titles.entry_id = exp_channel_data.entry_id', 'inner');
$this->db->join('exp_member_data', 'exp_members.member_id = exp_member_data.member_id', 'inner');
$this->db->where('exp_members.member_id', $this->db->escape(($_GET['cardid']-10000000))); 
$query = $this->db->get();
echo $query;
```

Is this safe enough or right approach or am i missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Last two approaches are correct to avoid SQL injection. On last code, using Active Record, you don't need to call escape as CodeIgniter will do it automatically.

Comment: In approach nr 2: which is right _______________
WHERE em.member_id = '".$this->db->escape(($_GET['cardid']-10000000))."'");

Or

WHERE em.member_id = '?'", array($this->input->get('cardid'-10000000)));

Comment: Both are correct but the second method is cleaner. On both methods you don't need to write quotes. $this->db->escape already adds quotes and you just need to write em.member_id = ? and CodeIgniter will set quotes automatically

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html